# iOS: UIView(CALAyerDelegate) Crash in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework, xcode8

I got this crash in xcode when testing an ios ionic app and I am stuck on what this is (please see screenshots below and highlighted line) or what needs to be fixed or caused the crash?

[image]

Comment: This is too broad - can you show your current code

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what in my code caused this because I am confused as to what this is in order to show something?

Comment: Does it happen when you launch the app? Does it happen when you launch a certain page? Does it happen when you click a button on a certain page? Are you using container views? Are you assigning a CALayer delegate to a particular view? You would show code and/or storyboard that is relevant to when the crash occurs. It is visual layer based because CALayer is visual.

Comment: That is the problem I have no idea, this was from a testflight test I looked in xcode and see a crash but have no idea what it is in relation to as it doesn't give that info in the crash, and no one reported an actual crash, something did freeze at one point on my end but otherwise nothing so I don't have much to go on code wise. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I mean it is too hard to troubleshoot without knowing more info. I would look for any place that you are using layered views or using a CALayer Delegate and see if you can find any possible holes in the code. https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/1668322-calayerdelegate

Comment: I didn't note that I'm using the Ionic 2 framework (ionic 2 beta 11) so I don't have much control over layers and this stuff, all I can edit is the HTML, CSS, and JS for my ios app. Does that make a difference? Thank you again.